# Libgdx cell horizontal align

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a table like this:

[image: http://prntscr.com/fkvzt7]

All what I want is to align easy, medium and hard texts in the middle of the cell, at least horizontally.
I searched a lot on how to do this, but I didn't find anything useful...
My code for the table is this:

```
table.setBounds(0, 0, Info.Width, Info.Height);
table.row();
table.add(label).expandX().colspan(3);
table.row().padTop(20).width(Info.Width);
table.add(easyText).width(Info.Width / 3).expandX();
table.add(mediumText).width(Info.Width / 3).expandX();
table.add(hardText).width(Info.Width / 3).expandX();
table.row().padTop(10);
table.add(easyHighscoreLabel).width(Info.Width / 3);
table.add(mediumHighscoreLabel).width(Info.Width / 3);
table.add(hardHighscoreLabel).width(Info.Width / 3);
table.row().padTop(50);
table.add(backButton).expandX().colspan(3);
```

Info.Width, Info.Height are the width and the height of the app.
label is the title: "HIGHSCORES".
easyText, mediumText, hardText are the texts I want to align.
easyHighscoreLabel, mediumHighscoreLabel, hardHighscoreLabel, are the numbers below the text.
And backButton is "Back" from bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setAlignment (int alignment)` on your label by default it is left center.

```
easyText.setAlignment(Align.center);
mediumText.setAlignment(Align.center);
hardText.setAlignment(Align.center);
```

This will align all the text by center within the label.